# Oracle to PostgreSQL DB Gateway?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, odbc, gateway

I intend to create a DB Gateway from Oracle to Postgres. I have the appropriate file (Setup) file for installation. 
Now, I after I execute the setup and proceeded with further steps.

- A new directory in Oracle_Home where DB Gateway will be installed.
- Selected the option for "ODBC" gateway.

The installation fails and says the following :

DB Gateway Error:

[image: DB Gateway Error]

Now if I see the errorlog file --> `configToolFailedCommands`

The log file says:

```
rem Copyright (c) 1999, 2009, Oracle. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32\cmd /c call
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\OraGtw11g_home2/bin/netca.bat /orahome C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\OraGtw11g_home2 /orahnam OraGtw11g_home2 /instype custom /inscomp client,oraclenet,server /insprtcl tcp,nmp /cfg local /authadp NO_VALUE /responseFile 

C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\OraGtw11g_home2\network\install\netca_typ.rsp
```

I do not know how to read the log file if it contains an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file mentioned by Oracle (configToolFailedCommands) is not an error log file but a script file allowing you to re run the commands which have previously failed.